# Make Greasemonkey throw error on undefined variable

Tags: greasemonkey

I've recently switched from chrome to firefox for greasemonkey development. I have some problems with debugging.

The following func

I meant to write:

```
    self = this;
```

but instead I wrote

```
this=self;
```

Self wasn't defined, so the script didn't run, however, nor did I get any javascript error. Why and can I get them somehow? I get some errors.

Comment: The script rather didn't run because you cannot assign to `this` than because `self` was undeclared (btw, [`self` is not undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self)).

Comment: What do you mean by "*I get some errors*"?

Comment: For example ReferenceError: callbacktest is not defined

Comment: for the code    var mycompany = new company(announcementID, callbacktest);

Comment: Then it's simple: The `this=self` code is not even entered because there are exceptions elsewhere in your script.

Comment: If I comment-out this=self, It runs. what I'm really is after is how to get greasemonkey to tell me what stops it from running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Greasemonkey - and javascript in general, along with at least a few other non-compiled languages - do not give very good debugging errors... I can't count the number of times it tells me there is a missing `)` at the end of an argument list that doesn't exist, and it turns out my error is elsewhere...

When a script of mine won't run I add an alert after any value assignments and if they don't alert or alert the wrong data I have found the problem... for your example above I would debug by:

```
this=self;
alert(self);
```

Although I would probably see the problem when I went to add the alert, but if I didn't notice - the alert either wouldn't pop up or it would have the wrong value... and if it didn't pop up, the error console would likely say `self not defined`.

Comment: People are gonna look back at the year 2014 and think we were primitive because we used 'alerts' to debug. Absolutely useless, we need real debugging for userscripts. Why is this so difficult? </rant>